# Why is state now undefined in ngrx app after reselect refactoring?

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx, reselect

I just went through my formerly working application and refactored it to use reselect as the ngrx example app [now does](https://github.com/ngrx/example-app/commit/0bd88242cadf243bdbec581417a833b5add6d14a). I don't have any compile errors but I have this runtime error:

```
error_handler.js:53 TypeError: Cannot read property 'token' of undefined
    at loggedIn (session.reducer.ts:46)
```

from this code in my [session.reducer.ts](https://github.com/dancancro/great-big-angular2-example/blob/reselect/src/app/core/store/session/session.reducer.ts#L46) file

```
export const loggedIn = (state: Session) => !!state.token;
```

which is a flag used in the main app page to show/hide the logged-in user's name. The page is almost totally blank and I'm having the same problem with the other parts of state being undefined. I'm not sure what to try.

Comment: I pulled your repo and was unable to find any issues with the store.

Comment: That's interesting. For me, it's not working at all. Did you check the 'reselect' branch? That's the one with the trouble.

Comment: No just master branch. I can look later this evening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `createSelector` to build your root reducer. Probably a typing mistake. You probably wants to `compose` your reducers functions :

```
const developmentReducer = compose(
    storeFreeze,
    localStorageSync(['session'], true),
    combineReducers)(reducers);

const productionReducer = compose(
    localStorageSync(['session'], true),
    combineReducers)(reducers);
```